# SQL CREATION OF TABLE ERROR in Oracle DB11g

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE BOATS( bid numbers(5), bname varchar2(10), color varchar2(6),
    primary key(bid));
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datatype of `bid` should be `NUMBER(5)`, not `NUMBERS(5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE BOATS( bid number(5) primary key, bname varchar2(10), color varchar2(6));
```